# separating index of children javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = $(".font-main-image").children("img").length;
    $("body .font-main-image").children("img").eq(0).show();
    var j = num;
    var i = 0;

    function main() {
        function toggle() {
            $("body .font-main-image").children("img").eq(i - 1).hide();
            $("body .font-main-image").children("img").eq(i).show();
            i = i + 1;
            if (i === num) {
                clearInterval(int);
                int1 = setInterval(toggleback, 90);
            }
        }
        var int = setInterval(toggle, 90);

        function toggleback() {
            $("body .font-main-image").children("img").eq(j - 1).hide();
            $("body .font-main-image").children("img").eq(j - 2).show();
            j = j - 1;
            if (j === 1) {
                clearInterval(int1);
                j = num;
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    setInterval(main, 90 * 2 * num);
});
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="font-main-image">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-01.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-02.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-03.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-04.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-05.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-06.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-07.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-08.svg">
</div>




<div class="font-main-image">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-01.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-02.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-03.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-04.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-05.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-06.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-07.svg">
  <img class="font-big-single-image" src="Ravi-08.svg">
</div>
```

I have few divs with same classes and and inside of them few img elements with same classes with display : none at my css and I want toggle between children(img elements with same class) from first to last and then from last to first and only have one display:block at a time so it will be some kind of animation.
note that there are few divs with the same class and the img elements inside of them have the same class as well and I want to loop through every div separately.

Comment: Where is the JS code?

Comment: its a long code and the problem is that jquery selects all of the children of every div and puts them in the same index and loop through them but i want to loop through the children of every div separate  if possible can i contact you by email?

Comment: Show that code, which targets all  the children of every div

Comment: i have added the whole code to the post

Comment: All your javascript use .image but it is not included in your HTML...

Comment: im so sorry it was an earlier version i was working on i have updated the code

Comment: the .image was the class of main divs it have been replaced with .font-main-image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way is through CSS animations, no need for JS:

```css
.font-big-single-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  animation-name: imgSwitch;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: imgSwitch;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 9s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imgSwitch {
  0% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1075'); }
  9% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1075'); }
  10% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1076'); }
  19% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1076'); }
  20% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1077'); }
  29% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1077'); } 
  30% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1078'); }
  39% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1078'); } 
  40% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1079'); }
  49% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1079'); } 
  50% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1080'); }
  59% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1080'); }
  60% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1081'); }
  69% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1081'); }
  70% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1082'); }
  79% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1082'); } 
  80% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1083'); }
  89% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1083'); } 
  90% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1084'); }
  100% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1084'); }
}

@keyframes imgSwitch {
  0% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1075'); }
  9% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1075'); }
  10% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1076'); }
  19% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1076'); }
  20% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1077'); }
  29% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1077'); } 
  30% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1078'); }
  39% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1078'); } 
  40% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1079'); }
  49% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1079'); } 
  50% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1080'); }
  59% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1080'); }
  60% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1081'); }
  69% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1081'); }
  70% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1082'); }
  79% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1082'); } 
  80% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1083'); }
  89% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1083'); } 
  90% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1084'); }
  100% { background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/400/400/?image=1084'); }
}
```

```html
<div class="font-main-image">
  <div class="font-big-single-image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: its actually a written website and the images are svg so i cant use background like that in css animation and also i cant write separate scripts for each main div so thanks but i dont think that will work